# Why TypeScript import CommonJS instead of ESM

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.sensedeep.com/blog/posts/2021/how-to-create-single-source-npm-module.html) to create a dual package. This is what the package file structure looks like:

```
my-awesome-lib
  package.json
  dist
  |-- mjs
    |-- package.json
    |-- index.js
  |-- cjs
    |-- package.json
    |-- index.js
```

In `package.json`:

```
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/mjs/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/mjs/index.js"
    }
  },
```

The `package.json` in the `mjs` folder:

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

The `package.json` in the `cjs` folder:

```
{
    "type": "commonjs"
}
```

---

In my Typescript application, I installed my own package, and tried to import it. However, I observed a wierd thing:

```
// src/index.ts
import { Class } from 'my-awesome-lib'
import { Class } from '../node_modules/my-awesome-lib/dist/mjs/index.js';
```

The 1st import statement points to the `../node_modules/my-awesome-lib/dist/cjs/index.js` instead of the `mjs` folder. The 2nd import statement is what I actually want.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong? Is it because I published my library in a wrong way?

---

p.s.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "module": "es2020",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

p.s. adding `{"type": "module"}` to the application's package.json doesn't make this error go away either.

Comment: Does the first import: `import { Class } from 'my-awesome-lib'` cause any errors? Presumably the code in **mjs** and **cjs** folders is functionally equivalent?

Comment: Try `"moduleResolution": "node12"` maybe? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#esm-nodejs

Comment: "*The 1st import statement points to …*" - what do you mean by that? Does the TypeScript language server provide it for autocompletion and referencing? Or does the (transpiled) code also import and execute the cjs code when executed?

Comment: @tromgy yes, the mjs and cjs codes are functionally equivalent, however, I do want to use the mjs version of my library for some reason.

Comment: @Bergi, `node12` doesn't seem to work. What I meant is, if I hover on `my-awesome-lib`, I can see where it points to, i.e. the cjs version of my library. I also tried to compile and run the code, and yes, I can confirm that it is actually using the cjs version.

I am super confused. I already used the `import` keyword, shouldn't typescript by default searches for the mjs version of my lib?

Comment: How do you run it? What does it transpile to? If node uses the cjs version as well, it might not be a TypeScript problem.

Comment: @Bergi you asked a very good question. I tried two things: 1. I use `tsc` to compile the source code, add `type: module` in package.json and run the application with `node dist/index.js`, and it turned out that node did know to use the ESM version of my library; 2. I then do the same thing, but this time with jest, and then the jest test failed. I then remove the `type: module` in package.json, and change the import statement to an absolute one (i.e. the 2nd import statement shown in my question), and test passed. Guess there is some issue with jest?

Comment: Does jest use babel to execute modules? I believe Jest doesn't support native modules yet since it cannot mock them

Comment: @Bergi, we can configure jest to support ESM. I worked around by only publishing the ESM version of my library.

Comment: @HUIJINGHUANG Yes, jest supports ES module syntax, but afaik not its native execution in node. Am I wrong? And are you saying that jest has extra configuration options to use the node ESM specifier resolution algorithm? Or did you achieve this only with the workaround of not providing a CJS version?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, there are tutorials that talk about how to configure jest to work with ESM. I don't have a good understanding about the specifier resolution algo, I just use the 'node' option iirc. The conclusion that I have right now is that, the issue that I had is likely caused by me creating dual packages in an incorrect way, therefore, as a workaround, I just provide an ESM version of my library. I can close this question, 'cause it might be misleading. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Everything is working as it was designed to. The problem your experiencing is a problem with what you expect. Your "tsconfig.json" file is improperly configured for an ESM module, yet you expect it to load the ESM package.

It looks like you are using **[`node16-strictest-esm-combined`](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node16-strictest-esm.combined.json)** as a reference, which if you are, I can tell you that this config threw me off as well about a year ago.

I really like the base/tsconfig repo, but only for CJS configurations. I don't know why they configure a tsconfig that has ESM in its name using `"moduleResolution": "node"`, but using `"node"` as the value is telling TypeScript to emit JavaScript that resolves as a CommonJS module.

###### [Here is the link to the official `moduleResolution` Documentation"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution)

It shows that the config bellow (which is the configuration I know 100% for sure trans-piles to ESM) is the correct configuration to use.

This is straight out of one of my projects that is an **"ESM"** package.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["ESNext"], // Why not use NodeNext if it compiles down anyways
      "target": "ES2021",

      // Runtime/Module
      "module": "Node16", // <- ESM Module Type
      "moduleResolution": "Node16", // <- ESM Resolution
      "esModuleInterop": false, // I added this to show what not to do

      // Project Structure
      "rootDir": "src",
      "outDir": "build",
      "declarationDir": "types",

      "strict": true,
      "alwaysStrict": false, // <- you can set this to false if your writing ESM
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },

    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.mts"], // You might want to change this
    "exclude": ["build", "types", "node_modules"]
}
```

#### You have 2 options

**NUMBER 1:**     To ensure that your project is an ES-Module: Your going to need to re-transpile your project. You have two options. You can either do it the way I prefer, *which is the way shown bellow:* using the build clean & force flags. Those extra flags ensure everything unnecessary is removed, and everything necessary is re-transpiled even if it wasn't modified. This is important, because your changing module type.

In **"ESM"** your `.js` files should emit with imports being imported using the **`import`** keyword, rather than the **"CJS"** `require()` method calls.
Because `tsc` tries to be efficient, it won't recompile the files that have require in them, because the corresponding `.ts` documents haven't been modified.

```
   $ tsc -b --clean
   $ tsc -b --force
```

**NUMBER 2:**     The other route you can take is to just delete your build & type directories, then run `$ tsc`. This way works too, but it requires either extra shell commands, or clicking of the mouse, where the other way is two `tsc` commands. Also the first method can be added to your package.json scripts property, and can later be called again quickly with `npm run`. You can also create typescript tasks for the `--build`, `--force`, & `--clean` flags.

*Anyways...*

Make sure that once you have re-transpiled your entire project (including all files), that your javascript files are using the `import` & `export` keywords, and not the `requires("...")` & `module.exports` property & method. Only then will you know that you actually have an ESM module.

#### At this point your ESM branch of your package should load

If it doesn't then you know its something with your packages configuration, which in that case you can message me and I can see if I can assist further.